# Concatenating lines using awk

Tags: awk, concatenation

I have fasta file that contains two gene sequences and what I want to do is remove the fasta header (line starting with ">"), concatenate the rest of the lines and output that sequence

Here is my fasta sequence (genome.fa):

```
>Potrs164783
AGGAAGTGTGAGATTGAAAAAACATTACTATTGAGGAATTTTTGACCAGATCAGAATTGAACCAACATGATGAAGGGGAT
TGTTTGCCATCAGAATATGGCATGAAATTTCTCCCCTAGATCGGTTCAAGCTCCTGTAGGTTTGGAGTCCTTAGTGAGAA
CTTTCTTAAGAGAATCTAATCTGGTCTGTTCCTCGTCATAAGTTAAAGAAAAACTTGAAACAAATAACAAGCATGCATAA
>Potrs164784
TTACCCTCTACCAGCACCAATGCCTATGATCTTACAAAAATCCTTAATAAAAAGAAATCCAAAACCATTGTTACCATTCC
GGAATTACATTCTGAGATAAAAACCCTCAAATCTGAATTACAATCCCTTAAACAAGCCCAACAAAAAGACTCTGCCATAC
```

Desired output

```
AGGAAGTGTGAGATTGAAAAAACATTACTATTGAGGAATTTTTGACCAGATCAGAATTGAACCAACATGATGAAGGGGAT
TGTTTGCCATCAGAATATGGCATGAAATTTCTCCCCTAGATCGGTTCAAGCTCCTGTAGGTTTGGAGTCCTTAGTGAGAA
CTTTCTTAAGAGAATCTAATCTGGTCTGTTCCTCGTCATAAGTTAAAGAAAAACTTGAAACAAATAACAAGCATGCATAA
TTACCCTCTACCAGCACCAATGCCTATGATCTTACAAAAATCCTTAATAAAAAGAAATCCAAAACCATTGTTACCATTCC
GGAATTACATTCTGAGATAAAAACCCTCAAATCTGAATTACAATCCCTTAAACAAGCCCAACAAAAAGACTCTGCCATAC
```

I am using awk to do this but I am getting this error

```
awk 'BEGIN{filename="file1"}{if($1 ~ />/){filename=$1; sub(/>/,"",filename); print filename;} print $0 >filename.fa;}' ../genome.fa

awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    BEGIN{filename="file1"}{if($1 ~ />/){filename=$1; sub(/>/,"",filename); print filename;} print $0 >>>  >filename. <<< fa;}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

I am basically a python person and I was given this script by someone. What am I doing wrong here?

I realized that i was not clear and so i am pasting the whole code that i got from someone. The input file and desired output remains the same

```
mkdir split_genome;
cd split_genome;
awk 'BEGIN{filename="file1"}{if($1 ~ />/){filename=$1; sub(/>/,"",filename); print filename;} print $0 >filename.fa;}' ../genome.fa;
ls -1 `pwd`/* > ../scaffold_list.txt;
cd ..;
```

Comment: Show your desired output.  Don't make us guess what _"concatenate the rest of the lines and output that sequence"_ really means.

Comment: Try `print $0 > filename".fa"` instead?

Comment: @John1024 i have added the desired output now

Comment: @EtanReisner it doesn't work. The same error as before

Comment: What version of `awk` is this?

Comment: @EtanReisner awk version 20070501

Comment: Is this Solaris or another Unix variant? I vaguely recall (but cannot find it at the moment) seeing that that error "illegal statement" is indicative of a very broken version of awk available by default on some commercial Unices and that it should be avoided at all costs in favor of other versions of awk they have optionally (in other locations).

Comment: @upendra, EtanReisner's fix makes your code work for me.  The output from that code, however, does not match your desired output.

Comment: Do you want all lines between headers concatenated to a single line, or do you want all lines in the file without headers to be concatenated to a single line?  The script you got is trying to print each sequence between headers to a file with base name of header.  Is this what you want?

Comment: _"desired output remains the same"_  The same as what?  The same as the code produces (with @EtanReisner's fix)? Or, the same as the desired output shown above?  If Etan's fix does not work for you, then you still need to tell us what OS and version of awk you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is produce the desired output shown in your question, other solutions will work.

However, the script you have is trying to print each sequence to a file that is named using its header, and the extension `.fa`.

The syntax error you're getting is because `filename.fa` is neither a variable or a fixed string.  While no Awk will allow you to print to `filename.fa` because it is neither in quotes or a variable (varaible names can't have a `.` in them), BSD Awk does not allow manipulating strings when they currently act as a file name where GNU Awk does.

So the solution:

```
print $0 > filename".fa"
```

would produce the same error in BSD Awk, but would work in GNU Awk.

To fix this, you can append the extension `".fa"` to `filename` at assignment.

This will do the job:

```
$ awk '{if($0 ~ /^>/) filename=substr($0, 2)".fa"; else print $0 > filename}' file
$ cat Potrs164783.fa
AGGAAGTGTGAGATTGAAAAAACATTACTATTGAGGAATTTTTGACCAGATCAGAATTGAACCAACATGATGAAGGGGAT
TGTTTGCCATCAGAATATGGCATGAAATTTCTCCCCTAGATCGGTTCAAGCTCCTGTAGGTTTGGAGTCCTTAGTGAGAA
CTTTCTTAAGAGAATCTAATCTGGTCTGTTCCTCGTCATAAGTTAAAGAAAAACTTGAAACAAATAACAAGCATGCATAA
$ cat Potrs164784.fa
TTACCCTCTACCAGCACCAATGCCTATGATCTTACAAAAATCCTTAATAAAAAGAAATCCAAAACCATTGTTACCATTCC
GGAATTACATTCTGAGATAAAAACCCTCAAATCTGAATTACAATCCCTTAAACAAGCCCAACAAAAAGACTCTGCCATAC
```

You'll notice I left out the `BEGIN{filename="file1"}` declaration statement as it is unnecessary.  Also, I replaced the need for `sub(...)` by using the string function `substr` as it is more clear and requires fewer actions.

Answer (score 1):

The awk code that you show attempts to do something different than produce the output that you want.  Fortunately, there are much simpler ways to obtain your desired output.  For example:

```
$ grep -v '>' ../genome.fa
AGGAAGTGTGAGATTGAAAAAACATTACTATTGAGGAATTTTTGACCAGATCAGAATTGAACCAACATGATGAAGGGGAT
TGTTTGCCATCAGAATATGGCATGAAATTTCTCCCCTAGATCGGTTCAAGCTCCTGTAGGTTTGGAGTCCTTAGTGAGAA
CTTTCTTAAGAGAATCTAATCTGGTCTGTTCCTCGTCATAAGTTAAAGAAAAACTTGAAACAAATAACAAGCATGCATAA
TTACCCTCTACCAGCACCAATGCCTATGATCTTACAAAAATCCTTAATAAAAAGAAATCCAAAACCATTGTTACCATTCC
GGAATTACATTCTGAGATAAAAACCCTCAAATCTGAATTACAATCCCTTAAACAAGCCCAACAAAAAGACTCTGCCATAC
```

Alternatively, if you had intended to have all non-header lines concatenated into one line:

```
$ sed -n '/^>/!H; $!d; x; s/\n//gp' ../genome.fa
AGGAAGTGTGAGATTGAAAAAACATTACTATTGAGGAATTTTTGACCAGATCAGAATTGAACCAACATGATGAAGGGGATTGTTTGCCATCAGAATATGGCATGAAATTTCTCCCCTAGATCGGTTCAAGCTCCTGTAGGTTTGGAGTCCTTAGTGAGAACTTTCTTAAGAGAATCTAATCTGGTCTGTTCCTCGTCATAAGTTAAAGAAAAACTTGAAACAAATAACAAGCATGCATAATTACCCTCTACCAGCACCAATGCCTATGATCTTACAAAAATCCTTAATAAAAAGAAATCCAAAACCATTGTTACCATTCCGGAATTACATTCTGAGATAAAAACCCTCAAATCTGAATTACAATCCCTTAAACAAGCCCAACAAAAAGACTCTGCCATAC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to print lines not started by `>` and in one line:

```
awk '!/^>/{printf $0}' genome.fa > filename.fa
```

With carriage return:

```
awk '!/^>/' genome.fa > filename.fa
```

To create single files named by the headers:

```
awk 'split($0,a,"^>")>1{file=a[2];next}{print >file}' genome.fa
```

Comment: No. `filename` is an awk variable being set by the `>`-prefixed lines.

Comment: Might want to add `END{print}` so the file is a complete line, but I'm not sure OP wants all lines to be concatenated, just the ones between headers.

Comment: This is no what i understood @EtanReisner

Comment: Not necessary for this example @JohnB

Comment: Look at the original (erroring) awk script. It is clear what it is trying to do.

Comment: @EtanReisner It sounds like OP wants something different than what the script he got is trying to do.

Comment: I don't think so @EtanReisner but no war here

Comment: Ah, it is entirely possible that the awk script in question doesn't do what the OP says they want to do. I focused on the error. I suppose we need to wait for clarification from the OP on what they *actually* want.

Comment: awk ``20070501`` (osx) .. added ``$0`` for portability @John1024